# Plus and minus sequence in Python

Tags: python, sequence

im creating a program which sums the values in a sequence, but it has alternate plus/minus.

I want to make the sum of this sequence 1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)....How can i use an alternate plus and minus just like the previous example?

Here is the code i have made so far:

```
s=input("Ingrese el numero de terminos a sumar:", )

sum=1.0
num=1.0

for i in xrange(1,s+1):
    ident=sum/(i+(i+1.0))
    sum=sum+-ident    

print "La suma de los",s,"terminos es %.2f"%(sum)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How can i use an alternate plus and minus just like the previous example?

Comment: don't use `sum` as a variable name

Comment: I assume you're learning python, python 3 would be a better starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise `-1` to the power corresponding to the index of whatever term you're on:

```
>>> (-1)**0
1
>>> (-1)**1
-1
>>> (-1)**2
1
>>> (-1)**3
-1
>>> (-1)**4
1
```

Hence, the whole summation can be simplified to

```
result = sum((-1)**i * 1.0/(2*i + 1) for i in xrange(s))
```

(You shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name, since the name is already taken by the [built-in function `sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) I used above.)

Answer (score 1):

A way that can be applied to a broader variety of applications can be to use a `bool`. Simply initialize it with the rest of your variables and change its value each time.

```
s=input("Ingrese el numero de terminos a sumar:", )

add = False
sum=1.0
num=1.0

for i in xrange(1,s+1):
    ident=sum/(i+(i+1.0))
    if add:
        sum += ident    
    else:
        sum -= ident
    add = !add

print "La suma de los",s,"terminos es %.2f"%(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the input:

```
n = input("Input how many numbers you want to add")
```

Afterwards, you can initialize the sum: (you may want to do some testing to ensure `n` is an `int`..)

```
total = 1
```

And then the loop. You can use some maths to check if you should add or subtract:

```
for i in range(3, 3+2*n, 2):
    if ((i-3)/2)%2 == 1:
        total -= (1/i)
    else:
        total += (1/i)
```

or using arshajii's little (and rather clever) trick:

```
for i in range(1, 1+n):
    num = 2*i + 1
    total += ((-1)**i)*(1/num)
```

Comment: `s` probably *is* an integer, actually.  The use of the `print` statement means the OP is working with Python 2.

Comment: @DSM in python2 the `input()` function does automatic conversion?? In the code above the OP does not convert to `int`

Comment: @RSerrao Yes, it does (assuming a valid int is entered).

Comment: `-1**i` is `-(1**i)`, which is always equal to -1. You need to put the `-1` in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

another version ...

```
def f(n): 
    return sum(pow(-1,x)/(2*x +1) for x in range(n))

print(f(4))
0.7238095238095239
```